# Fraction involving an exponent leading to a probable prime

Tags: number-theory

$\frac{541456}{5879}\approx 92+\frac{1}{10-\frac{1}{588+ \frac{216}{1000000000}}}$

How good is the approximation of the fraction $\frac{541456}{5879}$? Can the right expression be expanded with a continued fraction?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how good the right hand side is, then you want to find the size of the error $e$, where:

$\frac{541456}{5879} + e= 92+\frac{1}{10-\frac{1}{588+ \frac{216}{1000000000}}}$

Let's look at the right hand side first.

${588+ \frac{216}{1000000000}}=\frac{588000000216}{1000000000}$

$\frac{1}{588+ \frac{216}{1000000000}}=\frac{1000000000}{588000000216}$

${10-\frac{1}{588+ \frac{216}{1000000000}}}=\frac{5879000002160}{588000000216}$

$\frac{1}{10-\frac{1}{588+ \frac{216}{1000000000}}}=\frac{588000000216}{5879000002160}$

$92+\frac{1}{10-\frac{1}{588+ \frac{216}{1000000000}}}=\frac{541456000198936}{5879000002160}$

So $\frac{541456}{5879} + e = \frac{541456000198936}{5879000002160}$

$e = \frac{541456000198936}{5879000002160}-\frac{541456}{5879}$

$e = \frac{3183219825169544744}{34562641012698640}-\frac{3183219825169544960}{34562641012698640}$

$e=-\frac{216}{34562641012698640}$